# How can I access other class just to get info and then change in main?

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a function called getCrop() in order to change an label's img depending on the settings window but when i call the function in another class the img doesn't change why?

```
private JLabel label_9 = new JLabel("");

//This is inside class Normal(main).
public void getCrop(String str) {
    switch(str) {
    case "4446" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/4446.jpg")));
        break;
    case "3339" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/3339.jpg")));
        break;
    case "3446" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/3446.jpg")));
        break;
    case "4536" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/4536.jpg")));
        break;
    case "5346" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/5346.jpg")));
        break;
    case "11115" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/11115.jpg")));
        break;
    case "4437" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/4437.jpg")));
        break;
    case "3447" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/3447.jpg")));
        break;
    case "4347" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/4347.jpg")));
        break;
    case "3546" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/3546.jpg")));
        break;
    case "4356" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/4356.jpg")));
        break;
    case "5436" : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/5436.jpg")));
            break;
    default : label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/4446.jpg")));
        break;
    }
}
```

My Goal is to be able to change the img through my Settings window
Here is the code for when someone changes the comboBox the img should change too.

```
//City is an array of Strings
public JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(City);

comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
//this is inside Settings
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Normal cb = new  Normal();
            System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
            cb.getCrop(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    });
```

## EDIT 1:

I replaced getcrop for setVillageImg tanks for the tip

```
public static void setVillageImg(String str) {
    label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Normal.class.getResource("/TryBot/Resources/" + str + ".jpg")));
}
```

## EDIT 2:

It is now possible to access thank you all.
But when i change the first time it works but  i have to close the settings and open again in order to change the img again because if i try to change again it gives me an error

```
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? ( You should make the `getCrop` method static as it does not required the state of a `Normal` instance. Or perhaps )it should be part of the class that contains the `comboBox`.

Comment: You could rewrite a lot of that method to be much smaller. You could make have a list of supported strings (currently all your cases, except default). Then you only need to check if the string is contained in the list. If it is, then you can set the icon based on the string passed in (str [this could be better named also]), rather than all those unnecessary hard coded values.

Comment: And you should change the name of the getCrop method, as it doesn't get anything at all. You could call it setSomeLabelIcon(String strImageId), something like that, but change the Some part to be what that label is, rather than label_9, which again should be named more appropriately.

Comment: On a side note, your switch isn't needed at all. `"/TryBot/Resources/" + str + ".jpg"` should do the trick without bloating the code.

Comment: Do you know what `new Normal()` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your problem is the fact you create a new instance of the `Normal` class which is then changing the images of a label different than the one you see. You could remedy this by passing things around or making the method static; but that would add needless dependencies to the code when you could use other mechanisms.

If you have two classes (one for each of your settings and main views) why not add a controller in between them and have it as a listener of the `JComboBox` and an `Observable` to the main view? For example (*code includes simulation methods and statements to be removed*):

**MainView:**

```
public class MainView extends JPanel implements Observer {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel("");

    public void setVillageImg(String path) {
        // set the image
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        String path = (String)arg;
        System.out.println(path);
        setVillageImg(path);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class ViewController extends Observable implements ActionListener {

    public ViewController(Observer observer) {
        addObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Action Performed");
        setChanged();
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        notifyObservers(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
}
```

**SettingsView:**

```
public class SettingsView extends JPanel {

    private JComboBox<String> comboBox;
    private static final String[] strings = {"Hello", "World"};

    public SettingsView(ActionListener listener) {
        comboBox = new JComboBox<>(strings);
        comboBox.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public void simComboChange(int selected) {
        System.out.println("Simulating combo change");
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(selected);
        comboBox.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(comboBox, 0, "SimAction"));
    }
}
```

**Simulation `main`:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainView mainView = new MainView();
    ViewController viewController = new ViewController(mainView);
    SettingsView settingsView = new SettingsView(viewController);
    settingsView.simComboChange(0);
    settingsView.simComboChange(1);
}
```

---

**Background information:**

An [`Observer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) is a class which wants to observe another class for changes and act upon those changes.

The class that changes is said to be [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html). The two together are mechanisms of the Model-View-Controller pattern.

[`setChanged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#setChanged--) changes the state of the observable to changed. If you call [`notifyObservers()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers--) the observable should be checked for changes with [`hasChanged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#hasChanged--). [`clearChanged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#clearChanged--) sets the state back to unchanged. Both effect the return value of `hasChanged()`. Note that `clearChanged()` is automatically called by `notifyObservers()` and redundant in the code; therefore it's now removed.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't even know about a "Observer's existence".1ºs question what does setChanged(), clearChanged() and notifyObservers functions do? 2º Question what exactly is an Observer?

Comment: @pzmq, added the background information for those questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @pzmq, no problem, if it helps feel free to up-vote it as an indicator. If it proves to be your fix, feel free to accept it as the correct answer as well.

Comment: Just one more thing xD sorry to be a pain but now that i initialize the settings view up in Main how do i put it visible. Before i used to do inside the code of the Normal class something like new Settings.visible  but now i can't it says that it is an aplication and not a Frame

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of your design but it sounds like you need an "application" class that acts as the "main" frame to which you would add individual views to. But in the end the error is basically saying you need a frame so give it/make one. @pzmq

Answer (score 0):

Normal cb scope is limited to the actionPerformed method I believe and to the new Normal object you created. You need to call getcrop() on the label already inside your frame/ the already created Normal object in your frame, wherever it may be.